# Disabling Spring Boot argument parsing

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I would like to completely disable SpringBoot argument parsing.
Is there any way to do so?

**Why?**

The usage of my tool is something like:

`$ mytool --some-option=value -- --some-other-option=value arg1 arg2`

Notice the `--`.

By convention (see [guideline 10](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)) this is used as delimiter between  options and operands.

Currently, Boot's `DefaultArgument` sees this as an argument with an invalid name, and errors out.

I opened a Spring Boot [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14909) to treat `--` following convention.
But in the meantime I'd like to completely disable argument parsing, since I'm not using it anyway.

I don't think [this is possible](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L295-L296) in `2.0.x`, but I'd like to confirm with someone more familiar. Possibly get some idea about working around this.

**Example trace**

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --
    at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.parse(SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.<init>(SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments$Source.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at com.mypackage.genie.MyApplication.run(MyApplication.java:63)
(...)`

Comment: Is it possible to pass one argument in quotes (or double quotes) and parse in your tool ?

Comment: It is possible to edit the arguments on the fly before passing them to spring so that it doesn't choke. For example i can transform `--` into `---` (which Spring is ok with).

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want Spring Boot to parse the arguments you could change your main method so that they are not passed into `SpringApplication.run()`. You’re then free to process the arguments yourself in the main method, either before or after running your application.

Comment: Didn't think about this. Would work in terms of letting me pass any argument. However I would need some other mechanism to get the arguments passed down to my implementation of `CommandLineRunner::run` and the rest of the application. i.e. this requires some other kind of hack to pull in arguments from the side.